# Show that the following infinite series converges pointwisely

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f: \Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R$ is a continuous function satisfies $$|f(x)| \le {1\over 1+x^2} \forall x\in \Bbb R$$

For each $n \in \Bbb N$, let $s_n: \Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R$ be a function such that $$s_n(x)=\sum_{k=-n}^{n}f(x+k) \forall x\in \Bbb R$$

Show that the sequence of functions $(s_n)$ converges pointwisely to a limit function $s: \Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R$ such that $$s(x+1)=s(x) \forall x \in \Bbb R$$
Also show that s is continuous on $\Bbb R$

I try to prove  $(s_n)$ converges pointwisely: for fixed $x$,  $$\begin{align}|s_n| & \le \sum_{k=-n}^{n}|f(x+k)| \\
& \le \sum_{k=-n}^{0}{1\over 1+(x+k)^2}+ \sum_{k=1}^{n}{1\over 1+(x+k)^2}
\end{align}$$

So I think what I really need to prove is $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{1\over 1+k^2}$ converges? If yes, then I just use the fact $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{1\over k^2}$ converges.

So I guess the expression of $s$ is $\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}f(x+k)$. Hence, switching the summation index will not affect the sum, i.e. $s(x+1)=s(x)$

But how to prove $s$ is continuous? $s$ may not be uniform continuous, I cannot apply those theorems about uniform continuous.

Comment: Can you try to show that $(s_n)$ converges uniformly on a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, though your formulation ($|s_n(x)| \le \ldots$) would rather amount  to showing that $s_n$ is bounded.

For fixed $x$, we have $s_n(x)=f(x)+\sum_{k=1}^n(f(x+k)+f(x-k))$, and therefore we wonder whether the *series* with general term $a_k=f(x+k)+f(x-k)$ converges.
With $m:=\left\lceil \,|x|\,\right\rceil$ we see that for $k>m$ we have $a_k\le \frac2{(k-m)^2}$ and hence obtain convergence by comparison with $\sum\frac1 {k^2}$.

To show that $s$ is continuous, let us instead show that $s|_{[a,b]}$ is continuous for any closed interval $[a,b]$ (which immediately implies that $s$ is continuous as well):
Then, similar as above, as soon as $n$ is big enough, we find that $s_n-s_{n-1}$ can be bounded by something $\sim\frac1{n^2}$ on all of thge interval.

Comment: Isn't that $s_n$ is bounded implies $s_n$ is convergent?